# How are Booleans sorted?

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting, boolean, hibernate-criteria

I am sorting with the following code:

```
undoneCategories = session.createCriteria(Category.class);
undoneCategories.add(Restrictions.eq("Done", false));
undoneCategories.addOrder(Order.asc("UpwardGenerator"));
undoneCategories.setMaxResults(1);
```

where `UpwardGenerator` is `boolean`.

How will it be sorted? With `false` first, or with `true` first? What about `null`/`nil`/undefined values?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It will sort `false` first, since in the database `true` and `false` are represented as `1` and `0`, respectively.

Answer (score 4):

By default, `boolean`s are sorted with `false` first, followed by `true`.  This is because in binary `false` equals `0` and `true` equals `1`.  Hence the old C paradigm of `while(1) { }` (which, incidentally, doesn't compile in Java).